# JS: importing multiple web components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am pretty new to JavaScript and just playing around with web components. Now it's not clear to me about importing different web components and how to do it a correct way, if there is a correct way. Maybe you could take a look on a way how I do it until now and tell me some advantages and drawbacks according to it, it would be great. If you think I am doing it wrong I would appreciate if you could show me the way and explain why is it better.

***1st method*** (feeling wrong):

```
class WorkPanel extends HTMLElement {
    //stuff in here
}

window.customElements.define('work-panel', WorkPanel)
```

and

```
class Sidebar extends HTMLElement {
    //stuff in here
}

window.customElements.define('side-bar', Sidebar)
```

index.html

```
<body>
<side-nav></side-nav>
<work-panel></work-panel>

<script type="module" src="javascripts/workPanel.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="javascripts/sideNav.js"></script>

</body>
```

***2nd method***

it differs from the first one as I have an index.js where I have the content and it't the module itself containing the web components.

```
import './javascripts/sideNav.js'
import './javascripts/workPanel.js'

const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        div.content {
            display: block;
        }
        div.sidebar {}
        div.workpanel {}
    </style>
    <side-nav class="sidebar"></side-nav>
    <work-panel class="workpanel"><work-panel/>
    `;

class SiteContent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open"})
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    }
}

window.customElements.define('site-content', SiteContent)
```

index.html

```
<body>
<site-content></site-content>
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Is it better to have multiple modules loading each component or one module loading all components. How could it affect the performance or potentially the architecture later?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You defined `<side-bar>`, but you call it `<side-nav>`.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [CodeReview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preamble

You should not worry about performance unless you notice *significant underperformance*. Even then, don't optimize every detail but only the aspects that matter, identified by measuring, analyzing and benchmarking.

---

Both ways ensure the *execution order* of your scripts.

## Index `<script>` element

A single script that imports others has to be (partially?) downloaded before downloads of the others can start.

This could result in theoretically **slower loading times**, but practically it shouldn't affect loading times significantly, if at all.

A benefit of a distinct script per page is arguably **better organization**: All of a page's code is contained in a *single* "entry point" *JS-only* file. Any small code may be included as well, instead of having to link yet another small script.

Keeping a **more lightweight HTML** due to "deferred linking" *may* result in **earlier page rendering**.

## Individual `<script>` elements

Linking all resources explicitly provides the browser with all relevant URLs during initial scan/parse of the HTML. This may result in **faster loading times**.

Also, individual linking makes for **robust imports of independent scripts**: If a script that imports others fails to download, then those imports won't happen.

Linking all resources in the `<head>` section provides an **overview of all dependencies** with a quick glance at the HTML, which may be preferable.

---

Theoretically, many small scripts from the same origin may be downloaded slower than one large script, because many individual request have to be sent. This means: If possible, you should bundle as many scripts as possible.

However, a single large script tailored to each page individually is also not beneficial: Resources can be cached, but if those aren't ever re-used than caching them is pointless.

---

**Note**: [Scripts with `type=module` are deferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#module), so linking them late instead of early only prevents the browser to preload the resource. You should **always link resources early** (i.e. in `<head>`), and maybe even use [`<link rel=preload>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) for large resources.

Answer (score -1):

The is no *better* way; there is only *your* way, depending on your requirements

Note: `<template>` can be great, but are not required, your code can be condensed:

```js
import './javascripts/sideNav.js'
import './javascripts/workPanel.js'

customElements.define('site-content', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super() // sets AND returns the 'this' scope
      .attachShadow({mode: "open"}) // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot
      .innerHTML = `
          <style>
               div.content {
                  display: block;
               }
               div.sidebar {}
               div.workpanel {}
          </style>
          <side-nav class="sidebar"></side-nav>
          <work-panel class="workpanel"><work-panel/>`
  }
})
```

#### Dependencies

If you have dependenies, where Component **B** can only work when Component **A** is loaded;
use: `customElements.whenDefined`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined